# Objc ,GNUsetup make file adding clean rule

Tags: objective-c, gcc, gnu-make

I need to add somekind of clean all `*.obj` and `*.exe` files that has compiled 
I am not sure how can I do it in `GNUmakefile` .
This is what I have done until now , how can I add general clean rule ?

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make
TOOL_NAME = IntTest
IntTest_HEADERS = Fraction.h
IntTest_OBJC_FILES = main.m Fraction.m
IntTest_RESOURCE_FILES =

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't simply *make clean* work?

Or put extra cleaning commands under

before-clean::

after-clean::

(double colons)